# Postgresql query with double has_many relationships

Tags: postgresql

I have this complex data relationship.

POSTGRESQL FIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vm2z8qLuddzcHEgyaMnCbc/3

"Item Group" has many "items" through "item_ads" table.
So an Item Group has many part_number.

[image]

reports table contains the number of clicks for each day for each adgroupid.

Each *adgroupid* has_many *part_numbers*. (table: product_ads)

[image]

Now, I want to SUM all reports.clicks for each item_groups.id using the part_number to linked the tables.

After this, I have to consider only reports.adgroupid which are included in the part_numbers of item_group. So if "Item group" has three part_number (A, B, C) can be considered all adgroupid that contains A,B, or C but nothing more. If adgroupid contains part_number D it cannot be considered for clicks sum.

**Expected results**

[image]

I have to have a table with lots of item_group_ids.
I am looking for the PostgreSQL query to achieve this table.

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements for them as **text** into the post.

Comment: Side note: 9.1 isn't supported anymore. Consider upgrading.

Comment: BTW, you wrote what you want to achieve but you haven't asked any question.

Comment: I am looking for the PostgreSQL query. I tried a few things but they don't works

Comment: *After this, I have to consider only reports.adgroupid which contains at maximum all the part_numbers of item_group. So if Item groups has three part_number (A, B, C), if an adgroupid contains A,B,C and D it cannot be considered. If adgroupid contains (see product_ads relationship) A and B it's ok.* Please add some more demo data to make this clear, it's really difficult to understand from only one example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's build the query up in parts. It sounds like you already know how to get from `item_group` and `adgroup` to `part_number`, just not about how to join them. I've added a query that removes duplicates for part 1 of your question, but putting them into a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html):

```sql
WITH unique_part_numbers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT item_groups.id AS item_group_id,
                  part_number
  FROM item_groups
  JOIN item_ads ON item_group_id = item_groups.id
  JOIN items ON items.id = item_ads.item_id
)
SELECT unique_part_numbers.item_group_id, SUM(clicks)
FROM unique_part_numbers
JOIN product_ads ON product_ads.part_number = unique_part_numbers.part_number
JOIN reports ON product_ads.adgroupid = reports.adgroupid
GROUP BY item_group_id
```

About the second part - it's not possible to do it as you want, because you can have multiple adgroups per item_group - so I added adgroupid as an extra column. I create an array of part_numbers for the adgroup and check, using the [@>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) operator, that all parts that are from the `adgroupid` are also from the `unique_part_numbers.item_group_id`.

```sql
WITH unique_part_numbers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT item_groups.id AS item_group_id,
                  part_number
  FROM item_groups
  JOIN item_ads ON item_group_id = item_groups.id
  JOIN items ON items.id = item_ads.item_id
)
SELECT unique_part_numbers.item_group_id,
       product_ads.adgroupid,
       array_agg(unique_part_numbers.part_number),
       SUM(clicks)
FROM unique_part_numbers
JOIN product_ads ON product_ads.part_number = unique_part_numbers.part_number
JOIN reports ON product_ads.adgroupid = reports.adgroupid
GROUP BY item_group_id, product_ads.adgroupid
HAVING array_agg(product_ads.part_number) @> (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(other_product_ads.part_number)
  FROM product_ads AS other_product_ads
  WHERE other_product_ads.adgroupid = product_ads.adgroupid
)
```

Comment: 1) it's ok. 2) I get a double-counting but I cannot understand where.

Comment: Can you add some example data so I can test where I went wrong?

Comment: I think the error was that I wrote `WHERE other_product_ads.adgroup_id = product_ads.id` instead of `WHERE other_product_ads.id = product_ads.id`. I changed the query, it should work now

Comment: The double-counting was in part 2). Here all data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vm2z8qLuddzcHEgyaMnCbc/3
I think it's because items have "part_number_level2" that I haven't' said before and it duplicates data. How can I consider DISTINCT part_number?

Comment: In your example, both item 3468922 and 2796687 have item group 35940 and part number ABC123, so the item is duplicate

Comment: ok, how can I get distinct part_number in the join?

Comment: The main problem is that your data is polluted then, I'd try cleaning that up if possible, and add a UNIQUE constraint on `(item_group_id, part_number, part_number)` so no duplicate combinations can exist

Comment: I rewrote my answer, but it cost me a lot of effort. I think your database schema is not built for what you're trying to do. Consider not using `part_number` for `product_ads`, but just `item_id`. Also, `item_ads` doesn't do anything regarding ads, since it connects `item` and `item_group` as a Many-to-Many relationship

Comment: Ok, thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot change schema for other reason but I’ll take into account